# Hexadecimal Loops in C#

Tags: c#

My goal was to get a 3DES password and for that im missing the last 6 digits.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 16777215; i++)
{
    string hexValue = i.ToString("X").PadLeft(6, '0');
}
```

Comment: its not relevant to the question, also i get lots of posts turn down when i post too much things but here if you need:

Comment: string FileName = "DOCUMENTO1.dat";
                //char[] keyChars = { '9', 'D', '2', 'A', 'E', 'A', '5', '9', 'E', 'C', '1', 'C', '7', 'B', '5', 'A', 'D', '9', '1', '6', '8', '7', 'B', 'F', '6', 'C', '8', '2', '5', '8', '6', '2', 'F', '7', '6', 'B', '8', 'E', '9', 'F', '2', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };
                char[] keyChars1= {'9', 'D', '2', 'A', 'E', 'A', '5', '9', 'E', 'C', '1', 'C', '7', 'B', '5', 'A'};

Comment: char[] keyChars2 = {'D', '9', '1', '6', '8', '7', 'B', 'F', '6', 'C', '8', '2', '5', '8', '6', '2'};
                char[] keyChars3 = {'F', '7', '6', 'B', '8', 'E', '9', 'F', '2', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};

Comment: var key1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyChars1);

Comment: it was an example of what im doing, but that i will do myself, i cant just ask for everything, i erase the picture better then?

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the maximum number in your set of hexadecimals which goes from [0,FFFFFF] in decimal the set goes from [0, 16777215]

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 16777215; i++) {
  string hexValue = i.ToString("X");
  // your logic goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var allHexadecimals = Enumerable.Range(0, 0xFFFFFF + 1)
                                .Select(i => i.ToString("X").PadLeft(6, '0'));
```

Comment: it tells me that it cant convert String to Char, or that it can not join, how do i join the byte[] with this String?   var key3half = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyChars3);
                var key3 = key3half +allHexadecimals;

Comment: char[] keyChars3 = { 'F', '7', '6', 'B', '8', 'E', '9', 'F', '2', '3' };//, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};

Answer (score -1):

You can actually convert directly to Hex from c#, check out this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types

e.g. `for(int i = 0x0; i < 0xff;i+=0x01) {Console.WriteLine(iConsole.WriteLine(value.ToString("X"));}`

Comment: no but you get the range of numbers you want, and you can easily convert those to string in any format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#XFormatString